# Compute $\int_{\mid z\mid=1} \frac{e^{z}}{z^{n}}dz$ for all $n$ $\epsilon$ $\aleph$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How do I compute the integral

$\int_{\mid z\mid=1} \frac{e^{z}}{z^{n}}dz$ for all $n$ $\epsilon$ $\aleph$?

I know I should start with the Taylor expansion of $e^{z}$, which is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {x^{k}}{k!}$, and then I know I can apply the fact that
$\int_C f(z)dz = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Cf_{n}(z)dz$, but I'm not sure how to apply it and I don't know what to do from there. Thank you.

Comment: It is not always true that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_C f_n(z) dz = \int_C f(z) dz$.
However, knowing the series $f_n$ **converges uniformlly** (to $f$) - you can and should substitude the summation & integration order.

Comment: One can also use [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) for $f^{(n)}(0)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\aleph$? Normally $\aleph$ is used to denote (infinite) cardinal numbers (which need not be sets anyway).

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a good start. Finish off by using that
$$
\int_{|z|=1} z^k\,dz = \begin{cases} 0, & k \neq -1 \\ 2\pi i, & k=-1. \end{cases}
$$

(Which you probably know from before. If, not compute the above integral by parametrization.)

Answer (score 1):

$z=0$ is a pole of the function $\frac{e^z}{z^n}$.

Since $e^z=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{z^k}{k!}$ is an entire function, the residue theorem gives:

$$ \oint_{|z|=1}\frac{e^{z}}{z^n}\,dz = 2\pi i\cdot\text{Res}\left(\frac{e^z}{z^n},z=0\right)=\frac{2\pi i}{(n-1)!}$$
for any $n\geq 1$.